# View audio files by length - command line?

Tags: command-line, sound, files, execute-command

Is there a command(s) to view audio files sorted by length in the command-line?

For example the shortest to longest?

Comment: @terdon MP3 then,  since that's what I have the most of...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have `ffmpeg` installed, try:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *.mp3
do
  duration=$(ffprobe "$file" 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/ { print $2 }')
  echo -e "$duration\t$file"
done | sort -n
```

If you need only the filename, pipe the `sort` through `cut -f 2`.
Obviously replace `*.mp3` with whatever fits your needs.

`ffmpeg` understands pretty much any common (and not so common) formats.

Comment: Can I use `for file in *.mp3 && *.ogg && *ogg`? or use OR?

Comment: `&&` has a very different meaning in Bash.  Simply use `*.mp3 *.ogg`. Try from the command line `echo *.mp3 *.ogg` and see how it expands.

Comment: Oh right, thnx :)

Comment: Nice  Just wondering if it's also easy to filter out tracks that a longer than some threshold with this command?